# Validation of a stratified randomization plan

Tags: validation, stratification

In my team, we are conducting clinical trials using stratified block randomization with random block size.

Depending on the user, the randomization list will be generated using custom SAS macros or R functions.

As an illustration, here are the 10 first lines of the output for 3 stratification groups with `R`:
[image]

We would like to validate the output of these procedures, in a language-agnostic way, but I could not find any relevant algorithm.

For instance, it is obvious that the randomization list should have the same amount of patients in each arm across each stratification group. But I guess the blocks should behave in a certain way, and I'm sure there are many things I did not think of.

What would be a good strategy for the validation of randomization lists?
Is there any reference that lists the features it should have?

Related: [Stratified Randomization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320210/stratified-randomization)